# numpy irreversibly change items in a list at random

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a list

```
a = np.ones(100)
```

I want to turn 50 random items in that list to 0. Once those elements are 0, I want to turn 25 random elements of the remaining items in the list to 0. Of the remaining 25 ones, I want to turn 13 of the remaining elements to zero at random etc.

I will then run this through a simple loop e.g. (pseudocode) "if item == 1, print red particle, else print blue particle" etc.

This is basically to simulate exponential decay, but I'm struggling to think of an algorithm to do this.

This is not a duplicate of "Numpy: Replace random elements in an array" because once the elements have changed I do not want them to be considered for change again.

Comment: Just for the fun of it? Because `numpy` is so fast, that you will not notice whether the decay is exponential, linear or is the array contained only 0 to begin with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy: Replace random elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389481/numpy-replace-random-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: Shouldn't you always set 50 random elements to zero to get exponential decay?

Comment: Also, what is `a = np.ones(1,size=100)`? It's not even valid a legal function call.

Comment: Fixed. Not a duplicate for reasons explained above. It is 50% of the remaining items for exponential decay, not always 50.

Comment: 50% of all elements is the same as 50% of the remaining ones.

Comment: Most random decay processes would give each element an independent 50% chance of decay, rather than reliably decaying an exact proportion of the remaining items every time.

Comment: @user2357112 That's what I mean

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple version.  It's an alternative to the other answers and diverges from instructions by randomly setting elements to zero as is suggested for exponential decay rather than removing a deterministic 1/2 at each round.

This prints the entire array each round but alternatives could include the first element, print(a[0]), or the number remaining, print(a.sum()).

```
a = np.ones(100)
while any(a):
    print(a)
    for i, _ in enumerate(a):
        if random.random() > 0.5:
            a[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You are basically needing diminishing ones in the array and it seems with the additional constraint that the ones being replaced by `zeros` are only from the existing set of `ones`. To solve it, here's one way with [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with its optional arg `replace` set as `False` to get unique indices per iteration to assign `zeros` and using `np.flatnonzero` to get the leftover indices of `ones` per iteration.

Hence, the implementation would look something like this -

```
# Counts of ones to be set as zeros per iteration
counts = np.array([50,25,13,6,3,2,1])
a = np.ones(100,dtype=int)
for c in counts:
    a[np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(a), c, replace=False)] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [49]: counts = np.array([50,25,13,6,3,2,1])
    ...: a = np.ones(100,dtype=int)
    ...: for c in counts:
    ...:     a[np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(a), c, replace=False)] = 0
    ...:     print a.sum() # verify with summation of ones print at each iteration
50
25
12
6
3
1
0
```

To setup the `counts` array for a generic length input array `a`, we can do something like this -

```
N = int(np.log(len(a))/np.log(2)) # number of iterations
counts = (len(a)*((0.5)**(np.arange(N)+1))).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you want to implement it is to always set exactly 50% of the remaining elements to zero. This means in each epoch you will always decay **exactly** 50, 25, 12.5, ... elements.

However I don't believe that's how exponential decay processes work.

To my understanding you should, with a probability `p`, set each individual element to zero. This means for a probability `p = 0.5` in each epoch you will **on average** decay 50, 25, 12.5, ... elements.

This method also simplifies the solution a lot:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.ones(100)
p = .5  # probability of decay

for i in range(20):
    mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(x), p=[p, 1-p])
    x[mask] = 0
```

If speed is a factor (but memory consumption isn't), you can also vectorize this operation:

```
x = np.random.choice([-1, 0], size=(100, 20), p=[p, 1-p])
x = np.cumsum(x, axis=1)
x = x == 0
```

after which

```
x[:, n]
```

is your population after `n + 1` epochs and

```
np.sum(x, axis=0)
```

is the population size over time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it.  The essential idea is to create an array of indices [0, 1, 2, ..., 99], shuffle that array, and then uses slices of decreasing size from that array as the indices of `a` to be zeroed.

```
In [75]: a = np.ones(100)

In [76]: sizes = (len(a)*np.power(2.0, [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7]) + 0.5).astype(int)

In [77]: sizes
Out[77]: array([50, 25, 13,  6,  3,  2,  1])

In [78]: indices = np.arange(len(a))

In [79]: np.random.shuffle(indices)

In [80]: start = 0

In [81]: for k in range(len(sizes)):
    ...:     end = start + sizes[k]
    ...:     a[indices[start:end]] = 0
    ...:     print(np.count_nonzero(a))
    ...:     start = end
    ...:     
50
25
12
6
3
1
0
```