# Numpy: Change the element value of an array, it's a bit strange

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I created three arrays com,mask,r1,
and I wish to change a element values in r1[mask] for following test:

```
com = np.ones([8,8],dtype = np.int)              
np.fill_diagonal(com, 0)
com[0:3,0:3] = 0

replace_rate = 0.1
mask = np.random.choice([0,1],size=(com.shape),p=((1-replace_rate),replace_rate)).astype(np.bool)  

r1 = np.random.rand(*com.shape)*np.max(com) 
r1[mask][1]= 0.3

print(r1[mask][1])
print(type(r1[mask]))
print(r1[mask],r1.dtype,'r1mask' )
```

My question is why I can't assign values to the elements of r1[mask] as usual
I got the result of r1[mask] like:

```
[0.84356101 0.61487372 0.94783953 0.07359154] float64  r1mask
```

Where the second element does't change to 0.3.
how can I change the value?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `r1[np.where(r1 == r1[mask][1])] = 0.3` will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! But why it should be assigned in this way? I could change the element values like r1[0] = 0.3 in most of usual cases

Comment: It shouldn't don't use `where` like that. `r1[r1 == r1[mask][1]] = 0.3` works fine

Comment: What exactly do you expect `r1[mask][1] = 0.3` to do?

Comment: `r1[mask]` is a copy, not a view.  Assigning a value to that does not change `r1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I want to change the value of the element. The total purpose is to randomly change the element values of com . So I created a mask matrix to cover the elements changed. It's similar as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389481/numpy-replace-random-elements-in-an-array  And I found the r1[mask] will affect the final result. So I try to change it by hand and see how it will influence the result. But I can't assign the value to r1[mask] as usual, it's strange for me.  Thank you, Mad, this works!